# Getting "you can choose multiple items only if they are all located in the same folder" error

Tags: windows, angular, internet-explorer, filesystems

I have an Angular 4 app that allows a user to select multiple files for upload. When more than 20 files are selected, the document name turns blank (see screenshot) when you select less than 20, highlighted section looks fine and is populated.

My first thought is it's the file names. The file names appear to be UUID and after a certain length they no longer appear, but I'm at a loss on where to start with this. Then I thought it could be the file size, but the size of the files are negligible. (you can see the sizes in the screen shot. It would be nice to tell the customer what's causing the issue to give them a little guidance.

I did confirm all files are indeed in the same folder.

Anyone experience this issue? Any ideas what's causing this and what the fix may be?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in the config is no or a high file count limit.

For example, "angular4-files-upload" you can create a file limit in the components.ts file as seen below:

```
import {
  Ng4FilesService,
  Ng4FilesConfig,
} from './ng4-files';

...

constructor(
      private ng4FilesService: Ng4FilesService
  ) {}

private testConfig: Ng4FilesConfig = {
    acceptExtensions: ['js', 'doc', 'mp4'],
    maxFilesCount: 5,
    maxFileSize: 5120000,
    totalFilesSize: 10120000
  };

ngOnInit() {
    this.ng4FilesService.addConfig(this.testConfig);
}
```

Comment: Is this something put in by default by Angular? We never added a limit to any of the code. Also, Windows 10 is the only OS that gives us this issue. We have no issues on other OS's.

Comment: No, you usually have to do it yourself but you gave no background on any npmPackages you may be using or not. 

With you mentioning this being an OS specific issue, it may well be an issue between the package and the OS. Does it occur on one Windows 10 machines or all of them?

Comment: According to the client, it's on all of their Windows 10 machines. I tried it on a Windows 10 machine and it seemed to work fine. I guess I'll track down the versions and what software differences there are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a fix but maybe the cause.

I have an issue that results in the same error message (though not the disappearing file names) in my Java program.

From what I've found, the reason is the good old path length limit in Windows.
If the path of a selected file is too long, Windows will prefix the path with `\\?\` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation).

Now, if only some of the selected files have a path that is over the limit, only some of the files will have that prefix. No longer do all files have the same parent path! Windows is apparently doing a rather simplistic check (like a string comparison) to see whether selected files are in the same directory.

This seems to be reproducible with any app that uses the native Open File dialog.